# ruby on rails: post confirmation page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, confirm

i need post confirmation page

i have that form:

```
<%= form_for(@domainpost, :url => {:action => "confirm"})  do |f| %>


  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field" id="content">
  <b><p>Adres domeny: <span class="label label-important">Pole wymagane</span>
</p></b><%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "bez www." %> 
  </div>

  <div class="field" id="additiona">
    <p>Dodatkowe końcówki: </p><%= f.text_area :additiona, placeholder: "np. .de, .fr" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field" id="registerdate">
   <p>Data rejestracji domeny: </p><%= f.text_area :registerdate, placeholder: "DD-MM-RRRR" %>
  </div>
    <div class="field" id="expiredate">
   <p>Data ważności: </p><%= f.text_area :expiredate, placeholder: "DD-MM-RRRR" %>
  </div>
    <div class="field" id="registerin">
   <p>Zarejestrowane w: </p><%= f.text_area :registerin, placeholder: "miejsce rejestracji" %> 
  </div>
    <div class="field" id="price">
  <b><p>Cena: (jeżeli zostawisz to pole puste, w opisie domeny wyświetli się "do negocjacji")</p></b><%= f.text_area :price, placeholder: "w PLN" %> 
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Dodaj", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

in controler i put

```
def preview
  @domainpost = Domainpost.new(params[:domainpost])
end
```

and i in routes.rb i put

```
resources :domainpost do
    :confirm, :on => :collection
  end
```

but it dont work
any idea what i can do for post confirmation page?

Comment: How do you expect it to work if you have a route for confirm and action for preview? Also - you wish to preview a posting not a collection, don't you?

Comment: In the routes, resources :domainpost creates 7 default routes for your controller. you need to add "new" action to the controller and add @domainpost = DomainPost.new and in the "new.html.erb" add your html code. In the html no need to mention the ":url". And upon posting the form, you can catch the params in the "create" action of your controller. So add the "create" action to your controller and do the rest

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel ROTFL :D
@user2531122 Instead of `confirm` you can simply use default `create` action.